# Different ways to see a monad

Tags: functional-programming, haskell, monad, side-effect

While learning Haskell I have faced a lot of tutorials trying to explain what are monads and why monads are important in Haskell. Each of them used analogies so it would be easier to catch the meaning.
At the end of the day, I have end up with 3 differents view of what a monad is:

**View 1: Monad as a label**

Sometimes I think that a monad as a label to a specific type.
For example, a function of type:

```
myfunction :: IO Int
```

myfunction is a function that whenever is performed it will yield an Int value.
The type of the result is not Int but IO Int. So, IO is a label of the Int value warning the user to know that the Int value is the result of a process where a IO action has been made.

Consequently, this Int value has been marked as value that came from a process with IO therefore this value is "dirty". Your process is not pure anymore.

**View 2: Monad as a private space where nasty things can happen.**

In a system where all the process are pure and strict sometimes you need to have side-effects. So, a monad is just a little space that is allow to you for doing nasty side-effects.
In this space your are allow to escape the pure world, go the impure, make your process and then come back with a value.

**View 3: Monad as in category theory**

This is the view that I don't fully understand. 
A monad is just a functor to the same category or a sub-category.
For example, you have the Int values and as a subcategory IO Int, that are the Int values generated after a IO process.

**Are these views correct? Which is more accurate?**

Comment: #2 is not what a monad is in general. In fact, it's pretty much restricted to IO, and not a useful view (cf. [What a Monad is not](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/What_a_Monad_is_not)). Also, "strict" is generally taken to name a property Haskell *does not* posses (namely strict evaluation). By the way, Monads don't change that either (again, see What a Monad is not).

Comment: Techically, only third one is correct. Monad is endofunctor, for wich to special operation are defined - promotion and binding. Monads are numerous - a list monad is perfect example to get intuition behind monads. readS facilities are even better. Surprising enough, monads are usable as tools to thread state in pure functional language implicitly. This is not a defining property of monads: it is coincidence, that state threading may be implemented in their terms. Same applies to IO.

Comment: Common Lisp has its own compiler as part of the language. Haskell has Monads.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

Views #1 and #2 are incorrect in general.

1. Any data-type of kind `* -> *` can work as a label, monads are much more than that.
2. (With the exception of the `IO` monad) computations within a monad are not impure. They simply represent computations that we perceive as having side effects, but they're pure.

Both these misunderstandings come from focusing on the `IO` monad, which is actually a bit special.

I'll try to elaborate on #3 a bit, without getting into category theory if possible.

---

**Standard computations**

All computations in a functional programming language can be viewed as functions with a source type and a target type: `f :: a -> b`. If a function has more than one argument, we can convert it to an one-argument function by [currying](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Currying) (see also [Haskell wiki](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Currying)). And if we have just a value `x :: a` (a function with 0 arguments), we can convert it into a function that takes an argument of the [unit type](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unit_type): `(\_ -> x) :: () -> a`.

We can build more complex programs form simpler ones by composing such functions using the `.` operator. For example, if we have `f :: a -> b` and `g :: b -> c` we get `g . f :: a -> c`. Note that this works for our converted values too: If we have `x :: a` and convert it into our representation, we get `f . ((\_ -> x) :: () -> a) :: () -> b`.

This representation has some very important properties, namely:

- We have a very special function - the *identity* function `id :: a -> a` for each type `a`. It is an [identity element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Left_identity)  with respect to `.`: `f` is equal both to `f . id` and to `id . f`.
- The function composition operator `.` is [associative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Associativity).

**Monadic computations**

Suppose we want to select and work with some special category of computations, whose result contains something more than just the single return value. We don't want to specify what "something more" means, we want to keep things as general as possible. The most general way to represent "something more" is representing it as a type function - a type `m` of kind `* -> *` (i.e. it converts one type to another). So for each category of computations we want to work with, we'll have some type function `m :: * -> *`. (In Haskell, `m` is `[]`, `IO`, `Maybe`, etc.) And the category will contains all functions of types `a -> m b`.

Now we would like to work with the functions in such a category in the same way as in the basic case. We want to be able to compose these functions, we want the composition to be associative, and we want to have an identity. We need:

- To have an operator (let's call it `<=<`) that composes functions `f :: a -> m b` and `g :: b -> m c` into something as `g <=< f :: a -> m c`. And, it must be associative.
- To have some identity function for each type, let's call it `return`. We also want that `f <=< return` is the same as `f` and the same as `return <=< f`.

Any `m :: * -> *` for which we have such functions `return` and `<=<` is called a **monad**. It allows us to create complex computations from simpler ones, just as in the basic case, but now the types of return values are tranformed by `m`.

(Actually, I slightly abused the term *category* here. In the category-theory sense we can call our construction a category only after we know it obeys these laws.)

**Monads in Haskell**

In Haskell (and other functional languages) we mostly work with values, not with functions of types `() -> a`. So instead of defining `<=<` for each monad, we define a function `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. Such an alternative definition is equivalent, we can express `>>=` using `<=<` and vice versa (try as an exercise, or see [the sources](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/src/Control-Monad.html#%3C%3D%3C)). The principle is less obvious now, but it remains the same: Our results are always of types `m a` and we compose functions of types `a -> m b`.

For each monad we create, we must not forget to check that `return` and `<=<` have the properties we required: associativity and left/right identity. Expressed using `return` and `>>=` they are called [the monad laws](http://www.haskell.org/haskellwiki/Monad_Laws).

**An example - lists**

If we choose `m` to be `[]`, we get a category of functions of types `a -> [b]`. Such functions represent non-deterministic computations, whose results could be one or more values, but also no values. This gives rise to the so-called [list monad](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads/List). The composition of `f :: a -> [b]` and `g :: b -> [c]` works as follows: `g <=< f :: a -> [c]` means to compute all possible results of type `[b]`, apply `g` to each of them, and collect all the results in a single list. Expressed in Haskell

```
return :: a -> [a]
return x = [x]
(<=<) :: (b -> [c]) -> (a -> [b]) -> (a -> [c])
g (<=<) f  = concat . map g . f
```

or using `>>=`

```
(>>=) :: [a] -> (a -> [b]) -> [b]
x >>= f  = concat (map f x)
```

Note that in this example the return types were `[a]` so it was possible that they didn't contain any value of type `a`. Indeed, there is no such requirement for a monad that the return type should have such values. Some monads always have (like `IO` or `State`), but some don't, like `[]` or `Maybe`.

**The IO monad**

As I mentioned, the `IO` monad is somewhat special. A value of type `IO a` means *a value of type `a` constructed by interacting with the program's environment.* So (unlike all the other monads), we cannot describe a value of type `IO a` using some pure construction. Here `IO` is simply a tag or a label that distinguishes computations that interact with the environment. This is (the only case) where the views #1 and #2 are correct.

For the `IO` monad:

- Composition of `f :: a -> IO b` and `g :: b -> IO c` means: Compute `f` that interacts with the environment, and *then* compute `g` that uses the value and computes the result interacting with the environment.
- `return` just adds the `IO` "tag" to the value (we simply "compute" the result by keeping the environment intact).
- The monad laws (associativity, identity) are guaranteed by the compiler.

Some notes:

1. Since monadic computations always have the result type of `m a`, there is no way how to "escape" from the `IO` monad. The meaning is: Once a computation interacts with the environment, you cannot construct a computation from it that doesn't.
2. When a functional programmer doesn't know how to make something in a pure way, (s)he can (as the *last* resort) program the task by some stateful computation within the `IO` monad. This is why `IO` is often called a programmer's *sin bin*.
3. Notice that in an impure world (in the sense of functional programming) reading a value can change the environment too (like consume user's input). That's why functions like `getChar` must have a result type of `IO something`.

Comment: Great answer. I'd clarify that `IO` does not have special semantics from a language standpoint. It is *not* special, it behaves like any other code. Only the runtime library implementation is special. Also, there is a special-purpose way to escape (`unsafePerformIO`). I think this is important because people often think of `IO` as a special language element or a declarative tag. It is not.

Comment: @usr Good point. I'd add that [unsafePerformIO](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/System-IO-Unsafe.html#v:unsafePerformIO) is really _unsafe_ and should be only used by experts. It allows you to break everything, for example, you can create a function `coerce :: a -> b` that converts any two types (and crash your program in most cases). See [this example](https://gist.github.com/3693348) - you can convert even a function into `Int` etc.

Comment: Another "special magic" monad would be ST, which allows you to declare references to memory that you can read from and write to as you see fit (although only within the monad), and then you can extract a result by calling `runST :: (forall s. GHC.ST.ST s a) -> a`

Answer (score 5):

## View 1: Monad as a label

"Consequently, this Int value has been marked as value that came from a process with IO therefore this value is "dirty"."

"IO Int" is not in general a Int value (although it may be in some cases such as "return 3"). It is a procedure which outputs some Int value. Different executions of this "procedure" may yield different Int values.

A monad m, is an embedded (imperative) "programming language": within this language it is possible to define some "procedures". A monadic value (of type m a), is a procedure in this "programming language" which outputs a value of type a.

For example:

```
foo :: IO Int
```

is some procedure which outputs a value of type Int.

Then:

```
bar :: IO (Int, Int)
bar = do
  a <- foo
  b <- foo
  return (a,b)
```

is some procedure which outputs two (possibly different) Ints.

Every such "language" supports some operations:

- two procedures (ma and mb) may be "concatenated": you can creates a a larger procedure (ma >> mb) made of the first one then the second one;
- what's more the output (a) of the first one may affect the second one (ma >>= \a -> ...);
- a procedure (return x) may yield some constant value (x).

The different embedded programming languages differ on the kind things they support such as:

- yielding random values;
- "forking" (the [] monad);
- exceptions (throw/catch) (The Either e monad);
- explicit continuation/callcc support;
- sending/receiving messages to other "agents";
- create, set and read variables (local to this programming language) (the ST monad).

Answer (score 1):

Don't confuse a monadic type with the monad class.

A monadic type (i.e. a type being an instance of the monad class) would solve a particular problem (in principle, each monadic type solves a different one): State, Random, Maybe, IO. All of them are types with context (what you call "label", but that is not what makes them to be a monad).

For all of them, there is the need of "chaining operations with choice" (one operation depends on the result of the previous). Here comes into play the monad
class: have your type (solving a given problem) be an instance of the monad class and the chaining problem is solved.

See [What does the monad class solve?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21261427/is-chaining-operations-the-only-thing-that-the-monad-class-solves)